# sql select * as table name + column name

Tags: sql, alias

I have for example 2 tables: user, account

```
user: id, name, email, 
account: id, name, date
```

The query looks like this:

```
select * from user U
inner join account A on A.id = U.id
```

As a result I get the columns:

```
id, name, email, id, name, date
```

Is it possible to rename those column names to @first_letter_tableName + @column_name?
I would like to have sth. like:

```
select * as @first_letter_tableName + @column_name
from user U
inner join account A on A.id = U.id
```

Expected result columns:

```
Uid, Uname, Uemail, Aid, Aname, Adate
```

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: Not if you use `*`, which is bad practice anyway. Select the columns you actually need, then you can name them as you please -- `U.id AS Uid, A.id AS Aid`. If you absolutely want this done automatically, you're looking at some ugly dynamic SQL.

Comment: No, you need to explicitly use `AS` for each expression you want to name.